# Trouble with dual booting on a samsung laptop

Tags: installation, grub2, dual-boot, samsung

I am currently using a samsung np355v5 laptop (amd a6 processor with hd7520G integrated graphics) and I am trying to dual boot ubuntu 12.04 with windows 7. I ideally don't want to use wubi because I will doing a lot of file access programming which I am told is a fair amount slower with wubi.

So my problem is that when I install Ubuntu 12.04, the grub does not seem to overwrite the windows boot and so it still appears in the bios boot menu which has never happened with any other system I have used. This also means that for some reason windows does not appear in the grub boot menu. It does however show in /boot/efi/ but I can't translate this to the grub boot menu. OS prober does not see windows.

I would prefer having  it in the grub boot menu because I frequently use both os and booting from bios can be a bit of a nightmare sometimes.

Sorry if I missed any information out and thanks for the help in advance

Ross

Comment: Please don't end questions with your username. Fill in the name field at the profile page instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) in Ubuntu.

---

### Installing Boot Repair

1. Open the Terminal, then type:

   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update
2. Press Enter.
3. Then type:

   sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &)
4. Press Enter

### Using Boot Repair

Search for Boot Repair in the dash and launch it. Then click the "Recommended Repair" button and wait until it's finished.

---

Reboot. Does it work now?